# ¿Como obtener el año anterior al actual en django o pyhton?

Tags: python, django

Buenas Tardes como se obtiene el año anterior al actual en django, he intentado
hacer una resta de fechas pero me dice que no es un entero.

Comment: Hola Argenis Msy, deberías agregar un [mcve] que muestre lo que has intentado y la excepción completa. ¿Que tipo de dato son tus fechas exactamente? En Python con `datetime` puedes obtener el año anterior simplemente mediante el atributo `year` , p.e: `datetime.date.today().year - 1`

Comment: Gracias excelente, funciono a las mil maravillas

Answer (score 1):

En Python puedes utilizar el modulo `datetime` para trabajar con fechas, la función `today()` te permite obtener el tiempo actual.

Si deseas restar un año a la fecha actual puedes utilizar el atributo year y restar uno.

```
hoy = datetime.date.today()
ano_pasado = hoy.year - 1
```

Para más información puedes consultar la documentación sobre fechas en Python (En inglés) en este [enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
current_date = datetime.date.today()
```

si quieres el año anterior

```
prev_year =  current.year - 1
```

si lo que quieres restar un año a la fecha actual

```
prev_date = current_date - timedelta(years=1)
```